# Android ImageView scale type centerCrop

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm creating an activity on Android. I want to show a background image in it. I put a ImageView into my main RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bg4"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It makes view like this.

[image]

I need to make view like this
[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: change the heigh and width into wrap content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try set ImageView attribute `ScaleType=fitEnd` ?

Answer (score 1):

use this code.it's give the out-put as you want.
**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_height="150dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bgImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

one advice if u give the imageview width fill parent then it's contain whole space according to main container.
Best Luck

Answer (score 0):

Set the `android:background="@drawable/bg4"` in the `RelativeLayout` like that:

The whole XML should look like that:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg4
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That would fit the whole screen, not what OP wants.

Comment: As I understand, the size ot the `RelativeLayout` corresponds to the screen size - it has `match_parent` on the width and height attributes.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe there are a couple of things wrong in the xml:

RelativeLayout does not make use of an orientation, you should remove that

Is this your full xml file? If so then the alignParentLeft in the RelativeLayout doesn't do anything because that is an attribute you use if it's parent is a RelativeLayout.

fill_parent is the deprecated name of match_parent, you should use that.

I also believe that code you have would center the image on the screen putting anything that is to big evenly on both sides and not at all what you said it does.

If you just want a background you can just use `android:background="@drawable/bg4"` in the RelativeLayout

EDIT: Changing the layoutparams of the ImageView to wrap_content both height and width and removing the scaleType alltogether might make it like you wanted it to be.